# Jaspersoft Report using SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, jasper-reports

I have a stored procedure named P1.

I want to create a Jaspersoft report using the result of p1 assume p1 returns a result set.

p1 has set of parameters.

I don't know how to create report using stored procedure and how to pass parameters to my report.

Please guide me the steps to do this or correct me what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible to execute stored procedure with parameter in Jasper report. U must set your report's Query Language to Plsql first. Please refer this guide [ireport-calling-stored-procedures](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-calling-stored-procedures)

If u still have problem, i can show some example here.

Comment: I got the way after searching many sites. Thank you so much for your guidance.